# SOQL Parent Child Query Salesforce

Tags: soql, community, salesforce1-app, query, dynamic-soql

I am new to salesforce, I am using the below query to fetch data from Salesforce Approval Process, Here **actorId** is the Id which matches with the **Id** of User table. I need User **email** from the User table along with below values in the query. How can i do that?

```
SELECT SystemModstamp, Createddate, actorId, processinstance.status, processInstance. targetobjectid FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem
```

Comment: DO you need user email for sending email via Apex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use parent level subquery `actor.Email`

```
SELECT SystemModstamp, Createddate, actorId, actor.Email,
       processinstance.status, processInstance.targetobjectid 
  FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem
```

Comment: That is actor's email. Actor ID is same as User ID in User table. I need to match that user ID and get the User.Email. As both of the emails are different

Comment: @JohnK here Actor is a User. Only the field definition is changed for user. Actor.Email will give you the exact user details.

Comment: I have tried that, as the actor is who is assigning the approval process. But User is who is approving the line item. So both are different. In that case, i need User Email instead of Actor Email. The connection between Actor and User tables is ID. (ActorId and UserId). I have actor ID.